# SendGrid smtp not sending to Yahoo, AOL, or Verizon.net but sends to Gmail?

Tags: email, smtp, sendgrid

*(Disclaimer I'm fairly new to development in general and this is my first StackOverflow post all and any feedback is greatly appreciated.)*

I'm posting here because I'm on a free SendGrid account and their support team has yet to get back to respond and it's been over a week and I'm dying to solve this issue.

Currently, I'm using Sendgrid as an SMTP and recently my emails have stopped sending to the following esp Yahoo, AOL, and Verizon.net but emails send to Gmail just fine.

Because emails still send to Gmail I used "Email Header Analyzer" via mxtoolbox.com to review and meet the recommendations provided. Which I have implemented on. (See screenshot)

The only thing not checked off is the "DKIM Authenticated" in which it's my understanding that when you verify the domain you're using to send emails with SendGrid takes care of that for you.

It's not the email function itself because it sends just fine to Gmail.

My question is has anyone else experienced this issue? If so what was the fix you did that made it work?

**Screenshot of my email header analyzer results:**

[image: Screenshot of my email header analyzer results]

Comment: Your best bet is probably sendgrid's support crew.

Comment: Thanks, I reached out to them via Twitter too. I think because I'm on a free account our support issues are much less of a priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my SendGrid account was over the daily email sending limit for the "free plan" and the emails that were sent correctly to Gmail had been doing so because of a pre-existing mail function (not using SendGrid even though SendGrid was still logging these emails).

I figured out this was happening by looking at the "mailed-by:" info when you toggle the drop-down above the email just under the sender email address. [Mailed-ByView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pHMm.png) With SendGrid it would say "mail-by: sendgird.net" [SendGird-Mailed-ByView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41gPr.png)

It would have been nice if SendGrid made my sending limit information a little more apparent but you can find this information about your account by going to "Settings">"Account Details">"Your Products." [YourProductsView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9E8N.png)